# Тавтология или нет?

Tags: стилистика, тавтология

Скажите, пожалуйста, будет ли тавтологией такое предложение: "Охотники, уходя на охоту, приносили этому божеству жертвы"? И, если да, то как его можно перефразировать?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тавтологией не будет. Во всяком случае такой, от которой обязательно надо неукоснительно избавляться.

Но я бы поправил грамматический вид деепричастия. Здесь по грамматике уместнее "идя на охоту". А по логике и стилистике - "собираясь на охоту". В противном случае в Вашем изложении нарушается последовательность действий.

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом. "Охотник... на охоту" или "охотник охотится" это выражения, как "петь песню" и прочие. Можно оставить и эти варианты. Если же искать замену, то, может, подойдет по смыслу (просто вне контекста не совсем понятно), вместо охотников - мужчины, или вместо охоты - промысел?

Comment: Кстати, с "мужчинами" хорошая идея! Ведь, как я понимаю, речь о диком племени, а там "мужчина" и "охотник" — синонимы.